# How to access potential duplicate for a record?

Tags: duplicate-management

I have set up some [duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm&type=0/%22duplicate%20rules%22) on account object. These rules have identified potential duplicate accounts. I need to retrieve these potential duplicate accounts in code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the [DuplicateRecordItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterecorditem.htm) table for all records that have the same [DuplicateRecordSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterecordset.htm). First, query for all DuplicateRecordItem entries for the record(s) in question, then query for all DuplicateRecordItem entries for any of the DuplicateRecordSet entries for those DuplicateRecordItem entries. In this way, you'll have all of the record Id values for all potential duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I have one more question. Is there something like matching score on potential duplicates? I have gone through DuplicateRecordItem schema but didn't find anything.

Comment: @MangeshHonale No, the system is an all or none type thing, it doesn't assign scores. This is because the rules are built by admins, so admins have to define how specific records must match before they're linked as potential duplicates.

Comment: I already had the same sense but just wanted to confirm this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have observed a strange behaviour of this duplicate management system. I can see a lot of potential duplicates from lightning UI but when I look at DuplicateRecordSet and DuplicateRecordItem, I see only one DuplicateRecordSet with 3 records. Why is this happening? After setting up the matching and duplicate rules, will system identify duplicates from existing data or will only work on insert/update operations?

Comment: @MangeshHonale If they show up in the UI, they should show in the API as well. The system is indeed supposed to mark all duplicates over time, even if those records are not modified.